# How to remove closing tag of Xml using DOM

Tags: vb.net

I want to remove the closing tag of xml using dom.How to remove the closing tag ?

For Eg,

```
<tittle>
         <name>xxxx</name>
</tittle>
```

In the above example i need to remove

```
</tittle>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't, not using DOM, as the resulting XML isn't correct.

Comment: i am just asking the concept with the above example.i need to replace the closing tag.after that i will write the tag